# Laptop changes resolution when the lid is closed/opened

Tags: laptop, resolution

i've had a problem for the last couple of days where the resolution on my laptop changes when i close the lid

i'm running windows xp professional sp2 on a dell inspiron 1501
the video chip is an ati radeon xpress 1150 according to the catalyst control center software i've got installed which i think came with the drivers or something

i've seen this happen before but i installed an old game called road rash a couple days ago after seeing it mentioned on reddit and i'm wondering if it might be related

anyone know how i can stop this from happening? i have a workaround where i can manually change the resolution to something else and then change it back but that's a lot of work to do every time i close the laptop which is a lot

thanks!

Comment: Hmmm... I have the same notebook and it's happened a few times to me before. Problem is I don't remember how it got resolved but it hasn't happened for quite a while (possibly not since before I reinstalled XP in December). I'd try updating the driver like Wil suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I had this with a few Dell laptops belonging to clients which had Nvidia chips.

The solution was to update the drivers.

I have had a look at the ATI website and cannot see an update but take a look at this [Dell support page](http://support.euro.dell.com/support/downloads/driverslist.aspx?c=uk&l=en&s=gen&ServiceTag=&SystemID=INS_PNT_1501&os=WW1&osl=en&catid=&impid=) - I do not know if this was the original driver or a update, but hopefully it can help you.